# How do I make wxPerl work in Perl 5.10 on Windows?

Tags: perl, wxperl

Though I've tried several ways, I'm unable to make WxPerl to work on Windows.
I tried with both ActivePerl and Strawberry Perl.

The error I get is:

```
 Can't load 'C:/Perl/site/lib/auto/Wx/Wx.dll' for module Wx: load_file:Invalid access to memory location at C:/Perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 202.
```

Comment: Do you have enough space (1GB) on drive C: for Wx compilation?

Answer (score 4):

How did you install Wx?  Did you use a PPM or did you compile it yourself?

I have had good luck using ActivePerl and PPM files from [http://www.wxperl.co.uk](http://www.wxperl.co.uk/)/

Answer (score 2):

According ot my testing, wxPerl 2.8 doesn't work in Perl 5.10 on Windows XP SP2.
It does work in SP 3 and up..